# node-uuid IS installed but require('node-uuid') fails

Tags: node.js, require, pm2

I'm getting an error in my PM2 logs that indicates the line in my player.js Mongoose model that tries to load node-uuid is failing. I don't understand why because it is clearly installed and the node_modules folder and everything below it is owned by the user running the node app.

I'm completely baffled by this error...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the output of `ls node_modules/node-uuid` ?

Comment: why is pm2 installed in `/user/lib/node_modules` ? can you try installing node-uuid in this same directory ?